# cedet ede project for emacs

Tags: emacs, project, cedet

I am trying learn how to work with CEDET. I don't have any project to mess around so I want to shoot Emacs itself.

It seems CEDET automatically detects Emacs as a project when I open Emacs repository in dir. But when I do `M-x ede-find-file` there is no file to open.

Question is, How can I exactly setup Emacs as a project in CEDET to make use of EDE and other goodies of CEDET.?

Seems the [documentation](http://www.randomsample.de/cedetdocs/ede/ede/ede_002demacs.html#ede_002demacs) for this hasn't been completed yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `ede-find-file` doesn't provide completion.  If you are visiting some file in the Emacs source (like INSTALL) and do this:

```
M-x ede-find-file RET emacs.c RET
```

it should pop up emacs.c.

Different CEDET features all have different kinds of dependencies so it's hard to answer the question specifically, but generically, all you have to do is visit a file in your Emacs project, and the other features should be enabled.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I see from source, you mentioned that emacs has special ede project defined. could you elaborate about that.

Comment: There are many kinds of EDE projects.  The Emacs project is something so that Emacs will recognize the Emacs sources, and set up preprocessor symbols and include paths.  It doesn't do much else, but would be a good place to add new features if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that it should be added the same way as other EDE projects, with something like:

```
(setq emacs-project
      (ede-emacs-project "emacs-head"
           :file "/home/ott/work/emacs-head/README"))
```

At least this works for me...